# How to assign a service to message-driven-adapter in Spring Integration?

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-integration

Upon received message in receiveChannel I would like to invoke a service to do some extra work.
The flow of messages would be:

```
JMS Message -> receiveChannel -- message-driven-adapter --> jmsInChannel -> queueChannel (here the service should be invoked)
```

I would like to achieve this either with 1) a service that is invoked on queueChannel 2) or with a message-adapater.

In the latter case I do not know how to assign a service to message-driven-adapter in Spring Integration? Also a service is not invoked.

This configuration contains both approaches but none of them is working:

```
<int-jms:channel id="receiveChannel" 
    queue-name="FORWARD"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
    auto-startup="true">
</int-jms:channel>

<si:channel id="jmsInChannel"/>
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="messageDrivenAdapter"
    channel="receiveChannel" destination-name="jmsInChannel"/>
<si:bridge input-channel="jmsInChannel" output-channel="queueChannel"/> 

<si:channel id="queueChannel">
    <si:queue/>
</si:channel>


 <si:service-activator id ="activator" ref="messageService" 
    method="processMessage" 
    input-channel="queueChannel">
</si:service-activator>
```

And this is my sender that sends the messages to the FORWARD queue:

```
 <si:channel id="sendChannel"/>
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter 
connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
destination-name="FORWARD" 
channel="sendChannel"/>

<si:gateway id="forwardGateway" 
    service-interface="com.ucware.ucpo.forward.jms.MessageGateway" 
    default-request-channel="sendChannel"/>
```

Messages are coming from FORWARD queue in ActiveMQ backend.

Update: I added a listener and the messages are now received. This is the log file with TRACE turned on:

```
18.07.2013 15:52:16.036 [DirectChannel] [AbstractMessageChannel.java] [DEBUG] [main]
postSend (sent=true) on channel 'inputChannel', message: [Payload={FORWARD_ALL=3000, LINE=601}    
[Headers={timestamp=1374155536031, id=c2895e24-2260-4af8-9b23-a226ae95c31f,   
source=PRESENCE_ENGINE,userid=alice@tkb.local, type=FORWARD}]

18.07.2013 15:52:16.036 [ActiveMQMessageConsumer] [ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java] [TRACE] [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#1-1] ID:Lmiroslaw-PC-59127-1374155535776-1:1:1:1 **received message: MessageDispatch** {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, consumerId = ID:Lmiroslaw-PC-59127-1374155535776-1:1:1:1, destination = queue://FORWARD, message = ActiveMQObjectMessage {commandId = 11, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:Lmiroslaw-PC-59127-1374155535776-1:1:3:1:3, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:Lmiroslaw-PC-59127-1374155535776-1:1:3:1, destination = queue://FORWARD, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1374155536032, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1374155536013, brokerOutTime = 1374155536013, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@1bc4ec8, marshalledProperties = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@1d840d9, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {timestamp=1374155536031, userid=alice@tkb.local, source=PRESENCE_ENGINE, type=FORWARD}, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false}, redeliveryCounter = 0}

18.07.2013 15:52:16.037 [DefaultMessageListenerContainer] [AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#1-1] **Received message of** type [class org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage] from consumer [Cached JMS MessageConsumer: ActiveMQMessageConsumer { value=ID:Lmiroslaw-PC-59127-1374155535776-1:1:1:1, started=true }] of session [Cached JMS Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:Lmiroslaw-PC-59127-1374155535776-1:1:1,started=true}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`<int-jms:channel/>` is not used to start a flow - it's for providing message persistence mid-flow.

You don't need the first two elements; simply configure the message-driven adapter with `destination-name="FORWARD"` and it will receive messages from that queue.

Also, remove `queueChannel`; it's not needed; the service will be invoked on the listener thread.

`message-driven-adapter->jmsInChannel->service-activator`

Comment: Thank you for a prompt answer. This is the configuration I have after your suggestions. However, the service is still not invoked. `<si:channel id="jmsInChannel"/> 
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="messageDrivenAdapter" channel="jmsInChannel" destination-name="FORWARD" connection-factory="connectionFactory" /> 
<si:service-activator id ="activator" ref="messageService" method="processMessage" input-channel="jmsInChannel"> 
</si:service-activator>`

Comment: This implies no messages are being received from the queue. Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework`.

Comment: Indeed. The messages are sent but not received. Do you know why?

`[DirectChannel] [AbstractMessageChannel.java] [DEBUG] [main      ] postSend (sent=true) on channel 'sendChannel', message: [Payload=GATEWAY][Headers={timestamp=1374, id=b71f9]
[ActiveMQConnection] [ActiveMQConnection.java] [DEBUG] [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///172.16.33.49:61616@51596] notified failover transport (unconnected) of pending interruption processing
[PollingConsumer] [AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.java] [DEBUG] [task-scheduler-1] Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'`

Comment: Your configuration works perfectly fine for me; I suggest you turn on TRACE level logging to see the message flow on both sides. (TRACE gives details of the message listener container activity on the receiving side).